# Changing default value of a control programatically

Tags: ms-access, vba, default-value

I am trying to set the default of a control using VBA so that when I navigate away from the form and return later, the default value will be what I set it to previously.

I would expect this to work:

```
Private Sub searchButton_Click()
    Me.searchType.DefaultValue = Me.searchType.Value
End Sub
```

**Is it possible to set the default value of a control?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Persistant changes to the DefaultValue can only be made in DesignView. Look [here](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/767990-vba-how-make-form-properties-stick) and at Allan Browne's reply [here](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/199143-default-value-set-same-last-valus-field)

Comment: Seems odd.

Fair enough, I guess will have to make a table with the default value in it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess (it's not clear from your question) that you load a form, do stuff, save a default value, close (unload) the form. On a new load, you want to set the saved default value.

For that to work, you need to save the default value in a variable outside the form. Once you unload the form, all variables inside that form are released from memory.

So make a variable in the code module where you load the form.

As an example, put this in a code module:

```
Option Explicit
Public Default_value As Boolean

Sub jzz()

'load and show form
Load testForm
testForm.Show

'load and show form again
Load testForm
'set default value:
testForm.Default_checkbox.Value = Default_value
testForm.Show

End Sub
```

And a userform named testForm, with 2 elements, a checkbox named Default_checkbox and a Commandbutton.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub OK_button_Click()
'save default value in Module1:
Module1.Default_value = Me.Default_checkbox.Value

'unload form
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Cool idea. But I think I might just store the value in a table, rather than a variable in a module.

Comment: Database storage is better. Module variables get lost on error and when closing down the db, afaik.